# How to reuse vector images in wpf properly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, vector-graphics

### X problem:

I want to use vector graphic in WPF.

I have bunch of SVG files, which I can convert into XAML by using Inkscape. Resulting xaml is `ResourceDictionary` with `ViewBox` / `Canvas` containing `Path`, etc. Dictionaries are merged into `App.xaml` and I can use key to access them.

**Question: how to use such *images*?** It looks like I am not using them properly.

Here is how I am using them

```
<Viewbox Child="{StaticResource MyImageResourceKey}" Width="100" Height="100"/>
```

But it looks like I can use it only **once** (in one place)! Attempting to use that image in multiple places simultaneously will either remove it from previous place or will throw

> System.ArgumentException: Must disconnect specified child from current parent Visual before attaching to new parent Visual.

### Y problem

I want to show a list of vector images. I display them like this

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Viewbox Width="100" Height="100">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Image}"/>
            </Viewbox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

ViewModel

```
public class ViewModelSomeWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public class MyImage
    {
        public object Image { get; set; }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<MyImage> _images;
    public ObservableCollection<MyImage> Images
    {
        get { return _images; }
        set { _images = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
    ...
}
```

And items are added like this

```
Images.Add(new MyImage() { Image = App.Current.Resources["MyImageResourceKey"] });
```

Problem: when using **same** image (`"MyImageResourceKey"`) for second item, then first item displays (blank) image. If image is already displayed with the use of `StaticResource` somewhere, then adding item will throw above `ArgumentException`.

P.S.: I need to solve `Y problem`, but perhaps I am not using vector graphic properly.

Comment: Use x:shared =false in path and http://prntscr.com/5aoa21 and visit this link too http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @HeenaKishorPatil Consider adding your comment as answer, so the question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please Use **x:shared =false** in path as shown in attached image

[image]

and visit this link too for [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778(v=vs.110).aspx)