# Merged dictionaries in the App.xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, app.xaml, mergeddictionaries

I have a bunch of Xaml vector icons inside a separated `.xaml`. I load them inside my `window` using this directive:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/ScreenToGif;component/Themes/IconSet.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

I have lots of windows, so I would like to simply put this code inside the `App.xaml`.

I'm trying this:

```
<Application.Resources> <!-- Error, The property "Resources" can only be set once. -->
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="IconSet"> <!--Not sure why this?-->
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Mine;component/Themes/Theme.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>

<!--Here goes the rest of the file, with Style and DropShadowEffect... -->
</Application.Resources>
```

So here is the problem:

All examples don't use a `x:Key` attribute, but it gives me an error saying that I need.
When I do that, it says that I can't have multiple properties `Resource`...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Please see commented text

```
<Application.Resources>    
    <ResourceDictionary>           
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Mine;component/Themes/Theme.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <!--You have to add other style here only-->

    </ResourceDictionary>

<!--Not Here-->

</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks, just one more thing, you need to remove the `x:Key` attribute.

Comment: Now, I'm having some problems, for example, if I set a vector as child of a `ViewBox`, I can't set again to other `ViewBox`. I have to set the `child = null` to use elsewhere. If I just merge the dictionaries for each window, that won't happen.

Comment: Is your vector child in resource ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27172730/how-to-reuse-vector-images-in-wpf-properly?noredirect=1#comment42836349_27172730

Comment: No, but the canvas with the vector yes. It's alright now. Thanks again.

`x:Shared="False"`

Comment: Damn, I spent 15 minutes googling about this. And Heena Kishor Patil answer really works. So called intuitive error message :-D

Comment: @HeenaPatil Well explained. Saved my time.