# WPF C# Reflection: Iterate over all resources with build action "Page"

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, buildaction

I have a .dll with a lot of ResourceDictionaries.

The **build action** of all these ResourceDictionaries is set to **"Page"**.

Inside the Dll, I want to find all these ResourceDictionaries and iterate over them.

If I set the build action to "EmbeddedResource", I can use Reflection:

```
var embeddedResources = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames().ToList();
```

But GetManifestResourceNames() does **not** work for resources with build action "Page".

**How do I find or iterate over all resources that have the build action "page"?**

*The solution doesn't have to be Reflection. Any other way is very welcome.*

Thank you!

**Solution:**

Ladies and Gentleman! I have to announce, that the man of the week and the winner of this bounty, is Mr. Jon Wu. Jon Wu gave the right hint and through searching, I found this solution:

[Enumerating .NET assembly resources at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517407/enumerating-net-assembly-resources-at-runtime)

The working code, slightly changed looks like this:

```
public static string[] GetResourceNames()
    {
        var asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        string resName = asm.GetName().Name + ".g.resources";
        using (var stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(resName))
        using (var reader = new System.Resources.ResourceReader(stream))
        {
            return reader.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().Select(entry => (string)entry.Key).ToArray();
        }
    }
```

If you call this method, you get all the resource strings with a ".baml" at the end and you can iterate over them.

Thank you Jon Wu for the right hint.

Comment: Is this your answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file

Comment: @JohnPeters: No. As I explicitly wrote in the question, GetManifestResourceNames() only works for "EmbeddedResource". It does NOT work for "Page".

Comment: All "Page" marked items will go in a `<WpfApplicationName>.g.resources` .NET embedded resource that contains one stream per dictionary. These dictionaries are in the BAML format (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Application_Markup_Language#Technology) so I'm not sure if this is useful. What would you want to do once you have enumerated these BAML streams?

Comment: @SimonMourier: I load them into RAM with "obj = Application.LoadComponent(uri);". The problem is, once you compile them as EmbeddedResource, this doesn't work anymore, if the ResourceDictionaries have references to each other. With references, I mean imports with Uri-Packs. For example: You have a style RD, that imports colors from another RD with: <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles;component/Gray/Colors.xaml"/>.

Comment: Why don't you merge them in App like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27215155/merged-dictionaries-in-the-app-xaml and use App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries?

Comment: I added the solution to the question. Thanks to everybody who helped.

Comment: You should have told us you only needed the dictionary **names**. My initial comment gave the solution first

Comment: @SimonMourier It is right, that you gave the hint before Jon Wu, but I can not mark a comment as the right answer. I can only upvote them. Of course I only needed the names. If you use "EmbeddedResources" and you call Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames(), you will also only get the names of the resources. I think, I made it pretty clear, that I wanted GetManifestResourceNames(), but for "Page" resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145752/what-are-the-various-build-action-settings-in-visual-studio-project-properties),

> Page (WPF only): Used to compile a xaml file into baml. The baml is then embedded with the same technique as Resource (i.e. available as `AppName.g.resources`).

So it sounds like you just need to look for resources identified with  `YourAppName.g.resources`.

Comment: LADIES AND GENTLEMAN! I have to announce, that the men of week and the winner of this bounty, are Mr. Jon Wu and Mr.Thomas Levesque. Jon Wu gave the right hint and through searching, I found this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517407/enumerating-net-assembly-resources-at-runtime. I have added the solution to the question. Thank you, John Wu!

Comment: You get the bounty, but according to the rules, I have to wait 2 hours, before I can click on the award button.